# Android Development: What is the difference between simple_list_item1 and simple_list_item2?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I know that simple_list_item1 is used in Android for creating a ListView. What is simple_list_item2 for? Also, how do I change the overall look of a ListView?

Example Code:
ListView lv;
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));

Comment: check this : http://www.davekb.com/browse_programming_tips:android_simple_list_item1_and_simple_list_item2:txt

Answer (score 1):

simple_list_item2 is one LineListItem means have only one TextView

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@android:id/text1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft" android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight" android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

simple_list_item2 is TwoLineListItem means have 2 TextViews......

```
 <TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" android:mode="twoLine">

      <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft" android:layout_marginTop="8dip" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

      <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@android:id/text1" android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/text1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


</TwoLineListItem>
```

used in http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2008/03/my-first-meeting-with-simpleadapter.html